# Users do not display correctly in Lists on StackOverFlow

Tags: bug, status-declined

Users are not displaying correctly in IE 9
It seems to cut off the reputation of the user on the Users Page.

In addition, it cuts off the reputation of the user on Question and Answer lists.

Anyone else experiencing this?

[image]
[image]

Comment: @yoda screenshots are posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This only happens in IE7 "mode", which isn't supported (not is IE7 itself).  We support the latest version of a browser and the one before that.  Beyond that, the site will (where easily supported) remain *functional*, but may not be pretty.

You can find more support information the community keeps updated here:
[Which browsers are officially supported? And what else do I need?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/71208/135201)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys stupid me.  My kids (or me! LOL) must have hit Alt 7 and turned on IE7 Standards.  But this is good to know.  The StackOverflow pages will render poorly if running in IE7 Standards Mode.

Comment: We do not support IE7...so this is a known issue and won't be fixed.